# Vuforia – Can't see terrain when using Cardboard

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, terrain, google-vr

I'm developing an AR experience with a `terrain` (not smart terrain, just terrain in Unity) in Augmented Reality app, everything works perfect!

But when I'm trying to use the `see-through mode` of Google VR, I see the clipping planes, that are making the terrain entirely black (you can see this on screenshots).

What could be the problem?

[image: first]

[image: second]

Comment: Could you try to resize terrain (enlarge the scale of terrain game object)? When you make smaller the 3D game objects in Unity, textures can not be rendered successfully.

Comment: Thank you for attention to this question!
The problem is not in textures, but in clipping planes. I can see in the editor how they are clipping the terrain. If I turn the clipping planes off, then I will see the terrain.
But if I turn the clipping planes off, then the models will go outside the video, which looks not good

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of one of the cameras for the eyes in the editor?

Comment: Can you send an example of project where it does not works?

Comment: Can't you use smart terrain instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you see this issue (black clipping planes) when using the see-through mode of Google VR, try setting `Far` and `Near` Clipping Plane's parameters in Unity.

[image]